# R function output as object

Tags: r, list, function, object, arguments

I'm trying to set a function whose outputs must be available in another function. I mean:

```
`setObj<-function(argument){
  list(a=argument$a,
       b=argument$b,
       c=argument$c,
       d=argument$d)
}`
```

this is a function with argument `argument` that is a list with 4 fields (a,b,c,d).

```
`f<-function(x){
  setObj(argument=x)
  (a+b+c+d)/4
}`
```

`x` has the some fields of `argument`. So in the function `f()` I need to have available the objects a,b,c,d without taking the objects from the list.

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't this imply an `lapply` function? Not sure if you need to write a unique function for this

Comment: Why not save the `setObj` expression from `f()` with a name and subset `a`, `b`, etc.. from that name?

Comment: But you need to store your variables somewhere if you want them to be returned from your setObj function. You can not simply use assign.

Comment: Yes I could but the list has a lot of arguments and subsetting could not be so elegant and convenient.@DamianoFantini I'd like to storage my variables anywhere of course, but in the environment of f() function and not in the GlobalEnv. So with setObj() I'd like to storage them into f() and calling them with their name (a,b,c,d). I don't know if I made myself clear, I hope so. If not please tell me and I try to be better. Thanks.